# Facebook publish actions defined in another application's domain

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to use one facebook application to publish actions defined in another application's domain, is it possible to do so? I mean, can we change the settings of the action to make it globally available or specifically grant permission to some other application?

E.g. If I define a customized action in app1, let's say it's app1:laugh (it's fictional), then I try to use javascript test console (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/) to test the following code, I got an error:

**(#100) Application 184484190795 does not own xxxxxxxxxxxx action type**

```
<script>
window.postAction = function()
{
FB.api(
    '/me/app1:laugh',
    'post',
    { someobject: 'http://domain.com/12345' },
    function(response) {
       console.log(response);
    });
}
</script>
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1" scope="publish_actions">
Login
</fb:login-button>
<button onclick="postAction()" >
Post Action
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is an intentional limitation of the API; you can't post actions against other sites' objects, only on sites which are derived from your app's website or canvas URLs